# Mirror selection not working properly

Tags: uv, selection-tools, mirror

I've created a dragon model and now I'm trying to unwrap my model so I could later on texture it. I've wanted to simplify the process of creating seams by mirroring selection. For example, I have teeth and I don' t want to create seams for each tooth separately.

So here's my question to you:
Why does Mirror Selection fail all the time I try to mirror the selected vertices on my dragon model? I know that Mirror Selection works only in Vertex Mode.
I think the problem is somehow associated with the matter that I haven' t applied the rotation or scale of my model (even though I did lately) or with the fact my model wasn't originally on x-axis as I started creating this model really long time ago and I know I could have done many things differently.

Here's an image to describe my problem:
[image]

Comment: If your model is symetrical, why dont you cut it in half, add a mirror modifier and mark your seams ?

Comment: what kind of rotation does the mesh object have? Quaternian? XYZ euler?
Are the local axes aligned with the global axes? Is it symmetrical along the global x axis with the line of symmetry intersecting Y=0?

Comment: As I mentioned earlier I've done few things wrong, which I could have done differently. The thing is that I've already created animations for my model and when I cut my model in half and use the mirror modifier it would make my model have every move mirrored based on the left side of the dragon's body...

Comment: The object has XYZ Euler rotation and so does the parent of my model (which is armature of the model). And... your next question helped me alot... The origin of my model wasn' t in the middle of my model (I guess when I rotated my model to x-axis I forgot to set the origin back to the geometry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try those two things:

1. Check if your pivot point is set properly. It has to be in the middle of your x-achis. To set your pivot hit <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (or hit <kbd>SPACE</kbd> and type "set origin"). Then choose "Origin to Geometry" or "Origin to Center of Mass".

Now your mirror selection should work correctly. If not, also do point 2:

2. Delete one half of your mesh. add a mirror modifier. mark your seems. Apply your mirror.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. That' s exactly what I forgot to do (the first thing you mentioned) :)